# ChildActionOnly attribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Though i invoke action method from actionlink present in the view.Its giving me error "action 'Demo' is accessible only by a child request".

Comment: please add relevant code for the above problem

Comment: If you have a method with `[ChildActionOnly]` then it can only be called by `@Html.RenderAction()` (the whole purpose of `[ChildActionOnly]` is to prevent it be called via a link)

Comment: You can either use `@Html.Action` or `@Html.RenderAction` as @Stephen Muecke suggested

Comment: //Action and Controllerpublic                                                                class DemoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Demo
        public ActionResult MyView()
        {
            return View(new string[]{"Apple,Mango,Strawberry"});
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Demo()
        {
            return PartialView("Demo");
        }
    }

Comment: //View                                                                                           @section Body
{

    <div>This is body section</div>
    <br/>
    @Html.ActionLink("Demo","Demo","Demo")
}